# How do I get cut-n-paste to work for remote X clients

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, clipboard

I've ssh-ed into a Debian computer from a Ubuntu computer (via an intermediate computer) and have problems getting cut-n-paste to work. Neither can I select text and insert that using middle-click. There's no fancy cut-n-paste between computers, just copy text from one remote X client application to another remote X client application (or even the same X client application)

What I see is that when I paste in a remote X client application the content of the last cut/copy from a LOCAL X client application is inserted, as if cut/copy from remote X client application doesn't matter.

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh to a remote computer that does not affect copy&paste function at all. With ssh you can type commands on a remote computer, but that you are typing them in terminal that runs on your computer. You do not have any access to others computers clipboards. All copy&paste operations are done in your terminal.

Therefore you have clipboard of your computer and it does not matter on how many remote computers you are connected. You have figured it out correctly, that you copy something at your computer and you can paste that to a remote command prompt, but that is all happening in terminals that are running on your computer.